# Using Express JS app.get along with Promise pending inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, fetch

I am trying to implement an api route in my nodejs server called 'get_stock_data'.
However, once this route is used, the server calls another library to get the data, and in return sends it back. Currently if I try to log the response, it says Promise <>. Im not sure how I would add .then() and wait for the promise.

```
app.get('/get_stock_data', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const stockName = JSON.parse(req.query.data).stockName;     
    res.send(get_stock_data_request(stockName));
}
);
```

The get_stock_data_request is an async/await function that calls API libraries on nodejs.

Comment: So we can see the whole problem, it would be better if you showed the code for `get_stock_data_request()` in case there are problems in its asynchronous design.  While you say it is `async`, that doesn't guarantee a proper asynchronous design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `async/await` for request handler as well `(it's also just normal function ;-)`.

Try like this:

```
app.get('/get_stock_data', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        const stockName = JSON.parse(req.query.data).stockName;
        const response = await get_stock_data_request(stockName)
        return res.json(response) // If you get json as response otherwise use `res.send`
    } catch(err) {
       res.status(400).json(err) or .send(err)
    }
);
```

Comment: Does express.js already support async handlers? I doubt it. You should wrap it using something like `express-async-wrap` package

Comment: I mean if we have a global error handler we don't catch exception there without this special wrapping

Comment: No, you don't need any modules, Node js does support async/await above node 7.6

Comment: It supports it as keywords but it does not mean express.js supports async middlewares itself.

Comment: Yeah! I think you’re right, Express middlewares does not support async await

Comment: But, If you want to do some async/await stuff in middlewares, you can try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yL6xgekr)

Comment: @Anatoly - You are perfectly free to declare an express route handler as `async`.  Express itself will ignore the promise that is returned from that handler, but if you handle everything yourself inside the route handler (which is generally your responsibility anyway), then you can use `async` route handlers and can thus use `await` inside of them just fine - I do this all the time in my route handlers.

Comment: I suppose in a certain route handler you should handle only expected errors while parsing/processing inputs, checking access rights, doing some validations and so on. If it's something with a connection to DB (for instance) then it should be handled by a global error handler that sends 500 code and some error description to client meanwhile logging full error details to its own log.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `then` and `catch` to process a regular and error responses from `get_stock_data_request`

```
app.get('/get_stock_data', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    try {
      const stockName = JSON.parse(req.query.data).stockName;     
      get_stock_data_request(stockName)
       .then(result => res.send(result))
       .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
    } catch (err) {
       res.status(400).send('Error parsing query parameters')
    }
}
);
```

Comment: For completeness, you should have a `try/catch` around the `JSON.parse()` call and send an error if that throws.  That is one case that Naren's answer using `async` already covers.

Comment: JSON.parse is synchronous so that error can be catch by a global error handler

Comment: Uhhh, that's not a good strategy.  A request handler should handle it's own errors and send its own error response upon error.  And, it should protect against errors in user supplied data which is what `JSON.parse(req.query.data)` is.  I made a suggestion on how you could improve your answer and I was hoping you would take the opportunity to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding `await` so that should be
`await res.send(get_stock_data_request(stockName));`
if not try adding `res.send(await get_stock_data_request(stockName));`